# Android MapController crashing my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm creating a mapView activity and for some reason this code isn't working:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.map_view);
    MapView mapView = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.layout.map_view);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
```

This line specifically is causing the app to crash:

```
MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
```

When I take that line out, the app works like it should, but when I put it in, it crashes when I start the activity, with the error message:

```
07-05 21:27:24.857: E/AndroidRuntime(23801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uie.top25.seattle/com.uie.top25.seattle.MapDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my call to the mapView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.detail);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    ListData listdata = bundle.getParcelable("uie.top25.seattle.listdata");

    // int itemId = this.getIntent().getIntExtra(DiningActivity.ITEM_ID, -1);
    String itemTitle = listdata.getTitle();
    int itemNum = listdata.getItem();
    String sHead = listdata.getSubhead();
    String dText = listdata.getDetailText();
    final float latitude = listdata.getLatitude();
    final float longitude = listdata.getLongitude();
    Log.i(TAG, "Title that is set : " + itemTitle);
    Log.i(TAG, "Item Number that is set : " + itemNum);
    Log.i(TAG, "Latitude that is set : " + latitude);
    Log.i(TAG, "Longitude that is set : " + longitude);
    if (itemNum >= 0)
    {

        TextView tView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        tView.setText(itemTitle);
        TextView nView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
        nView.setText("" + itemNum);
        TextView subHead = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textSubheader);
        subHead.setText(sHead);
        TextView details = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        details.setText(dText);
        ImageButton mapButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.mapButton);
            mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                             //this is where I call my mapView from
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, MapDetailActivity.class);
                    //mapIntent.putExtra("uie.top25.seattle.listlat", latitude);
                    //mapIntent.putExtra("uie.top25.seattle.longitude", longitude);

                    startActivity(mapIntent);

                }
            });
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone give me some direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try replacing this line:

```
 MapView mapView = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.layout.map_view);
```

with this one:

```
 MapView mapView = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.id.<your mapView Id>);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
 MapView mapView = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.layout.map_view);
```

You are Linding Layout `mapView` wont get initialize try to change with ID i.e.

```
 MapView mapView = (MapView)this.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
```